# How to combine printf and readline in Perl

Tags: perl, printf, readline, prompt

I'm trying to replace STDIN with readline. If I use STDIN (like in comment, see code) the cursor is ready for input right after printf output in the **same line**. But using readline the printf output is somehow gone and only the readline prompt is visible. I can insert a "print "\n";" (commented out) in the next line to printf which moves the prompt to the next line and printf output is visible. But, I want to have a formated prompt and the cursor directly after the prompt (**same line**). The printf assignment is a bit more complex than in the example below.
Is it feasible with printf or what are my options?
Thanx in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Term::ReadLine;
use Term::ReadKey;
my $term = Term::ReadLine->new('name');

printf "%-12s","Input: ";
# my $new_value = <STDIN>;
# print "\n";
my $new_value = $term->readline('--> ');
```

Comment: As choroba mentioned, you might be suffering from buffering: See http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html for details

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the output of `printf` is delayed is buffering. To avoid it, you can use STDERR which is not buffered and maybe more suitable for this kind of output:

```
printf STDERR '%-12s', 'Input: ';
```

Or, you can make STDOUT flush more often:

```
local $| == 1;
```

Another option is to use `sprintf` instead of `printf` and put the whole expression to the prompt:

```
my $new_value = $term->readline(sprintf '%-12s-->', 'Input: ');
```

Comment: I find it useful to use output streams in a manner consistent with their naming. So, I don't use `STDERR` for outputting anything other than error or log messages. I find it counterproductive to recommend using `STDERR` for its buffering characteristics rather than in a manner consistent with its name. Further, `$|` is a flag. Therefore, assigning a value rather than incrementing or decrementing it is the proper thing to do. Only your last recommendation has real merit: If one wants a specific prompt, one should provide the full prompt text.

Comment: you should use `$|=1` or `local $|=1;` not `$|--`. If someone had already set it to 1 you would end up turning autoflush off. Also it doesn't disable buffering, it only causes Perl to flush the contents of the buffer more often. Which is why it is often called the [autoflush variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%7c).

Comment: Thanks to all of you - interesting discussion. I'm using `sprintf` now. It works fine as long as the case is as simple as here. I have learned a lot.