# Perl loop not printing out character

Tags: perl

This one has got me.

This works:

```
print "Processing Feed\n";
while ( my @p = $mainex->fetchrow_array ) {
    my $iis = "$pcount";
    print "$iis\n";
    # ... Do Other Stuff Here
    $pcount++;
}
```

Which gives:

```
Processing Feed
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
...
```

This does not work (removed the \n from line 4):

```
print "Processing Feed\n";
while ( my @p = $mainex->fetchrow_array ) {
    my $iis = "$pcount";
    print "$iis";
    # ... Do Other Stuff Here
    $pcount++;
}
```

Which simply gives:

```
 Processing Feed
```

I was trying to build a counter that would output the count of the record it was up to using something like:

```
while( Something ){
    print "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b";
    print "$count";
    $count++;
    # Do stuff here
}
```

Any ideas why when there is no \n in the second example nothing is printing to screen? I have done it many times before and cannot figure out why it is not working.

Comment: You don't need to force `$count` to be a string in `print "$count";` as [`print`](http://p3rl.org/print "perldoc -f print") forces it to act as a string. So just write `print $count;`. As for `print "$iis\n";` vs `print $iis, "\n";` in that case it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The newline at the end of the print triggers a flush of stdout, which prints to the screen.  If you add `$|++` to the top of your perl script, it will turn on autoflushing for stdout and you will see your numbers.

Comment: $i = 0;
while($i != 1000){
        print ".";
}

Comment: Jonathan Leffler answered this--the buffer will be flushed automatically once there's enough in it.

Comment: @l_t: it will flush in chunks of the buffer size... so you can see probably n x buffersize characters (but probably not all) ...

Comment: You should set [`$|`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%7c) explicitly to a value. What if someone turned on auto-flushing by setting [`$|`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%7c) to `-1` (`$|--`)? You would end up turning auto-flush back off of course. So always explicitly set [`$|`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%7c) to a true value `$| = 1`.

Comment: @BradGilbert well sure but, chances are, if someone doesn't know about $|, it's not going to be set to -1 :P

Comment: Except there was [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373892/how-to-combine-printf-and-readline-in-perl/15374665#15374665) which [(previously) suggested that you use `$|--` to turn autoflush on](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15374665/1). At any rate it is a flag, so you should really treat it as such.

Answer (score 4):

Buffered I/O.

The data is flushed to the screen when there's a newline, or when the buffer is full (which may be 512 bytes or 4096 bytes or some other fairly substantial number).